# offsetChange callback not invoked on Android 4.0.4 while using Libgdx Live Wallpaper

Tags: android, libgdx, live-wallpaper

I made a live wallpaper using [Libgdx for android](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ApplicationConfiguration#Live_Wallpapers).

It is working fine on devices below 4.0.4 but on devices having operating system 4.0.4 and above my live wallpaper is not getting callback in `offsetChange()` listener.  Libgdx is [forwarding the Android `onOffsetChanged()` callback](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidLiveWallpaperService.java#L584).

Comment: Which version of Libgdx are you using?

Comment: There were a lot of live wallpaper fixed merged into the nightlies (See https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/306).  I don't think this has made it into a "stable" release yet.  I don't know if this would fix your specific problem, though.

Comment: I have already tried that but some phones like galaxy s3 galaxy note2 are not giving onffsetChange() callback.

Comment: I have the same problem. I think it doesn't work because of TouchWiz wrapper which is used in Galaxy Series.